# what triggers thumbnail image on variation change - woocommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce, gallery, product-variations

we have own functionality for variation selection which is alternative for this (from variable.php):

```
wc_dropdown_variation_attribute_options(
array(
'options'   => $options,
'attribute' => $attribute_name,
'product'   => $product,
)
);
```

We have html/php structure (this is just example):

```
<select id="someId" class="" name="attribute_<?php echo esc_attr($attribute_name); ?>" data-attribute_name="<?php echo esc_attr($attribute_name); ?>" data-show_option_none="yes">
<option value=""><?php echo esc_html('test test'); ?></option>
<?php foreach ($options as $option) : ?>
    <option value="<?php echo esc_attr($option); ?>" <?php echo selected(sanitize_title($product->get_attribute($attribute_name)), $option); ?> class="attached enabled">
        <?php echo esc_html($option); ?>
    </option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Structure like this is working fine, problem is only that the picture is not changing on variation selection. So I wonder what is trigger in html/php structure to change variation the image.

Thanks for help

Comment: All variations data is included to the form tag. You need to add some custom jQuery/JavaScript code to detect the selected variation change and display the related image… Maybe [this can be useful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64613811/how-to-get-current-selected-variable-product-specific-data-in-woocommerce/64622584#64622584) or some answer [in this list](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A3730754+%5Bjquery%5D+variations)

Comment: Thanks I will check ..for now I was try to compare values but no trigger('click'), no adding or removing selected class on thumb didn't work to show desired image ...