# Display attributes term description for the selected variation in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, taxonomy-terms, product-variations

In WooCommerce under Products > Attributes > [Name of Attribute] > Add New [Attribute Variation] there is a section titled "Description", how to display the description attribute instead of the description of **{{{ data.variation.variation_description }}}** in the variation.php file?

I've tried [How to get current selected variable product specific data in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64613811/how-to-get-current-selected-variable-product-specific-data-in-woocommerce/64622584#64622584) answer code, but don't know how to show the attribute description.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This doesn't require using JavaScript or jQuery. With the following, you will be able to replace the variation description with attributes term description(s):

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_variation', 'display_available_attributes_term_description', 10, 3 );
function display_available_attributes_term_description( $data, $product, $variation ) {
    $terms_descriptions = array(); // Initialize variable

    // loop through attributes variation
    foreach( $data['attributes'] as $attr_taxonomy => $term_slug ) {
        $taxonomy = str_replace('attribute_', '', $attr_taxonomy);
        // Check that is not a custom attribute
        if( ! taxonomy_exists($taxonomy) ) {
            continue;
        }
        $term_id = get_term_by('slug', $term_slug, $taxonomy)->term_id; // Get the term ID
        $term_description = term_description( $term_id ); // Get the term description
        // Check that term description is not empty
        if( ! empty($term_description) ) {
            $terms_descriptions[] = $term_description; // Add the term description to the array
        }
    }
    // Replace variation description with attribute(s) term description(s)
    if( count($terms_descriptions) > 0 ) {
        $data['variation_description'] = implode(' <br>', $terms_descriptions); // stringify the array
    }

    return $data;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and works.

---

If you want to keep the variation description, and display attributes term description after it, replace:

```php
$data['variation_description'] = implode(' <br>', $terms_descriptions);
```

with:

```php
$data['variation_description'] .= ' <br>' . implode(' <br>', $terms_descriptions);
```